# unpack Clear spot .bin firmware update

Tags: linux, binary-analysis, unpacking, firmware

I am trying to unpack a clear spot firmware update

The firmware I am trying to reverse can be found on the [download page of the vendor](http://www.clear.com/support/download/spots/clear-spot-voyager)
I have used the fwtools to unpack the firmware as described on [this page](http://hackspot.net/iSpotBlog/?p=177).

After I did this, I managed to get a "kernel.bin" and a "rootfs.bin".
Now I want to include a new/additional certificate to this modem and make some edits on the administrator page that is within this modem (a Wimax one).

So I checked the rootfs file using the `file` tool. And I got the following output:

```
rootfs.bin: Linux Compressed ROM File System data, little endian size 4280320 version #2 sorted_dirs CRC 0xbf224100, edition 16777728, 268441607 blocks, 1325400384 files
```

This was no to little help so I gave binwalk a try and I got this:

```
  DECIMAL         HEX             DESCRIPTION
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0               0x0             CramFS filesystem, little endian size 4280320 version #2 sorted_dirs CRC 0xbf224100, edition 16777728, 268441607 blocks, 1325400384 files
8               0x8             Squashfs filesystem, big endian, version 2.1, size: 4276396 bytes, 1028 inodes, blocksize: 65536 bytes, created: Fri Jun 22 23:02:36 2012
```

But for doing the entire firmware file I got the following output.

```
    root@bt:/pentest/reverse-engineering/binwalk# ./binwalk -m /pentest/reverse-engineering/binwalk/magic.binwalk /root/fwtools_20100826c/bin.linux/imw.bin

DECIMAL         HEX             DESCRIPTION
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
855032          0xD0BF8         CramFS filesystem, little endian size 4280320 version #2 sorted_dirs CRC 0xbf224100, edition 16777728, 268441607 blocks, 1325400384 files
855040          0xD0C00         Squashfs filesystem, big endian, version 2.1, size: 4276396 bytes, 1028 inodes, blocksize: 65536 bytes, created: Fri Jun 22 23:02:36 20
```

As this did stoke me as odd I didn't continue. I don't know how to unpack the firmware. I think I have tried about everything I know you can do manually, firmware mod fit, fwtools, the whole lot!

Can someone shed some light on my issue and tell me how to continue?

Comment: So ... did you managed to extract the files ?

Answer (score 7):

You can extract them with either a hex editor or `dd`.

**To mount them you do:**

- `mount -t cramfs -o loop /firmware/cramfs /mnt/cramfs/`
- `mount -t squashfs /firmware/squashfs /mnt/squashfs`

Comment: Or just use `cramfsck`/`unsquashfs` to extract the image. Or 7-zip.

Comment: not working at all !

Comment: @AhmedRhuma Instead of putting "not working at all!" please eleborate what is going wrong. What the results are of your attempts what you tried etc.. etc.. Try to be constructive

Comment: okay i'm sorry for that ,, 
the mount says error ,, can't mount 
i'll tell you where i am now 
i extracted the squashfs from the .bin firmware 
but ether Firmware Mod Kit won't extract it ,
can you please download the bin file and trying help me !

Comment: this error :
root@bt:~/fwtools_20100826c/bin.linux# mount -t squashfs rootfs.squashfs /mnt/point/ -o loop
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

Comment: After trying it myself I have to say I am sure it is a false positibe like @devttys0 mentioned. Or they have tried something like https://code.google.com/p/firmware-mod-kit/issues/detail?id=2

Comment: can you help me more than this , please ?

Comment: After downloading a different firmware from the same vendors. And using meld to compare the two. You'll notice the files are nearly identical (C910 and the C611). You can clearly determine where the headers are found. Hope that helps you in the right direction.

Comment: here is where i am , 
this is the rootfs.squashfs i get it with dd 
http://www.mediafire.com/?0j5a4hjoah0m0p0
can you check it for me please ?
i'm a beginner and came here to learn ^_^

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10641/discussion-between-stolas-and-ahmed-rhuma)

Answer (score 7):

The CramFS image is a false positive; I doubt there would be over 1 billion files in a 5MB firmware image.

It looks like your binwalk signatures are a bit old; here is the output from mine (running the latest from the trunk):

```
DECIMAL     HEX         DESCRIPTION
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
14944       0x3A60      LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x6D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: -1 bytes 
855040      0xD0C00     Squashfs filesystem, big endian, version 2.1, size: 4276396 bytes, 1028 inodes, blocksize: 65536 bytes, created: Fri Jun 22 23:02:36 2012
```

The LZMA image is the Linux kernel and can be decompressed using p7zip or a similar utility:

```
$ p7zip -d 3A60.7z

7-Zip (A) 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,1 CPU)

Processing archive: 3A60.7z

Extracting  3A60

Everything is Ok

Size:       3072188
Compressed: 5120472
```

You won't be able to mount the SquashFS image, it is non-standard, likely "hacked up" to support LZMA compression. Unfortunately, I couldn't quickly find a version of unsquashfs that would extract the image; your best bet is to put in a GPL request with the company (I didn't see any GPL info on their downloads page), or to find a similar firmware which does have a GPL code release.

Comment: heh, well spotted!

Comment: yeah i split the squashfs section from hexdump and dd 
now i can't extract it cuz as you say it's non-standard " sqsh"
any other help !

Comment: are you ask for this ? http://www.infomark.co.kr/oss/lgpl.html

Comment: or this ? http://www.infomark.co.kr/oss/gplv2.html

Answer (score 1):

For those who can't get it to work with the already suggested answers, try this as Igor Skochinsky said in the comments because it was the only thing that worked for me.

> Or just use cramfsck/unsquashfs to extract the image. Or 7-zip

I used 
`7z e file.cramfs`
and it extracted all files perfectly.